# error while loading shared libraries libzlog.so

Tags: cmake

I have a project that uses zlog. There are no errors while compiling, but  I got this if I try to execute it:

> error while loading shared libraries: libzlog.so.1.2: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I can find the .so library in `/usr/local/lib`, and I have added `link_directories(/usr/local/lib)` to Cmakelists.txt

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable has been setted to `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: I am running the project on Ubuntu, and after executing sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I am running the project on Ubuntu, and after executing `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v`, the error disappears.